# Fewer things that work better

Tags: grammar, meaning

I came across a marketing blurb that says:

> Fewer things that work better
>
> [image]
>
> Source: https://www.modular.com

From a grammar perspective, what does that mean? Does it mean that the product doesn't have as many things that work well compared to other products?

Comment: If the syntax is confusing you, you can substitute "which" for "that," and recognize that it's a sentence fragment just like "unparalleled performance." In both cases the understanding is something like "We offer ____." But yes, no matter how you parse it, it's really easy to interpret it as "We don't have as many things that work better." Even to a native speaker this screenshot is unintentionally humorous and should be embarrassing to the company. (Maybe they used AI!)

Comment: @AndyBonner: I kinda doubt that sideswipe at AI's slogan-generating prowess! If an advertising department came up with that phrasing after spending *days* polishing it, they'd probably be quite pleased with themselves! In fact, it seems to have been coined by [Eric Karjaluoto - Creative Director at Microsoft in 2007.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=Eric+Karjaluoto++%22fewer+things+that+work+better%22) As a *request*, not a boast!

Comment: User1974: In case it's not obvious, I think the phrasing is *very* clever (the "ear-catching" equivalent of "eye-catching" high fashion). It's not intended as a vehicle for teaching English to non-native Anglophones, though, obviously!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrasing isn't great, but what they mean is that their product provides fewer "things" (tools, in this case), but their fewer tools work better than competitors' many tools. It's a double benefit: less complexity because there are fewer tools, but you still get all the benefits of having a ton of tools, plus some (because they work better).

Comment: In retrospect, I can't endorse "The phrasing isn't great". It's by far the cleverest thing I've read on ELL today!